# Using a MemoryStream with FileStreamResult possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetzip

I'm using DotNetZip to create a zip file and pass it to a FileResult. On debug, I can verify that the MemoryStream contains a file, but when I run it through FileStreamResult, it returns 0bytes:

```
public FileResult GetZipFiles(int documentId) {
       var file = fileRepository.Get(documentId);
       var zip = new ZipFile();
       var stream = new MemoryStream();

       var filePath = Path.Combine(UploadsFolder, Path.GetFileName(file.Id));

       zip.AddFile(filePath);
       zip.Save(stream);

       var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip") 
                    { FileDownloadName = "hey.zip" };

       return result;
 }
```

Again, I can verify that stream is not empty, but this will always return the file `hey.zip` as 0bytes. I must be using `MemoryStream` wrong here? Or `FileStreamResult` does something I'm not expecting it to do? I've used `FileStreamResult` before, but not with `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have you tried setting `stream.Position = 0;` after you do the `zip.Save(stream)`?

Also, you might confirm that data is actually being written to the stream.  Check `stream.Length` after `zip.Save`.  If `stream.Length` is zero, then nothing's being written.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, -1 for the second because he's already seen it's not empty in the debugger.

Comment: @Joel: Guess I missed that one.