# "This stream does not support seek operations"

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, stream, byte

I get a stream form a web service:

```
Stream resultStream = WebServiceEntities.GetAttachment(attachmentId);
```

[image]

I need to convert this stream into a byte array but

Attempt # 1

```
byte[] resultBytes = null;
using (Stream stream = resultStream)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
            ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
        } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);
        resultBytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Attempt # 2:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
resultStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
byte[] resultBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

In both cases the (byte[] resultBytes) always returns an empty byte array, does anyone know what is causing this to happen? Is there something wrong with the Stream the web service returns?

Comment: Have you tried putting the stream position at 0? `resultStream.Position = 0`.

Comment: @Marcus Hello Marcus, I can't do that, If I assign Position=0 to it, I get the following exception: "This stream does not support seek operations."

Comment: The data in `m_ReadBuffer` may well just be SOAP stuff - its presence doesn't indicate that the attachment had any actual data.

Comment: @JonSkeet So the Stream returned by the web service might be wrong?

Comment: @EricBergman: No, it might just be empty - the problem may be somewhere completely different. I suggest you look at the raw response from the server (e.g. via Wireshark or Fiddler) to see what's happening.

Comment: Set `memoryStream.Position` to 0 after you do the `CopyTo`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3702448/56778

Comment: @JimMischel That didn't work either, the byte array still returns empty.

Comment: Have you single-stepped in attempt #1 to confirm that bytes are actually being read?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, have you found any solution yet?