# ASP.Net MVC sending file without content size. Browser doesnt prompt save dialog until transfer is finished

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing on the fly file zipper.

I cant calculate correct file size of a future archive, so can specify Content-Length.

This code did not prompt save file dialog until both Thread.Sleep() methods returned.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        return new DelayedUnsepcifiedLengthZipArchiveResult();
    }
}

public class DelayedUnsepcifiedLengthZipArchiveResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        context.HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = "private";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", "test.zip"));
        context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        context.HttpContext.Response.Write("hello world");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        context.HttpContext.Response.Write("hello world2");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

In Chrome and IE 10 I got save dialog after 20 secs...

Is it a way to fix it?

Update:

Fidler goes crazy. Not sure, maybe Fidler adds Conent-Length automatically. This is raw data I getting from fidler

At the start

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/zip
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcV29ya1xBY2FkZW15XEhpZ2hMb2FkQ2hhblxEb3dubG9hZGVyXGhvbWVcZG93bmxvYWQ=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2013 13:39:24 GMT
```

After download finished:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/zip
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcV29ya1xBY2FkZW15XEhpZ2hMb2FkQ2hhblxEb3dubG9hZGVyXGhvbWVcZG93bmxvYWQ=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2013 13:39:24 GMT
Content-Length: 23

hello worldhello world2
```

UPDATE 2:

```
fiddler coused such veird behaviour, problem closed. Turn off your debug proxies bros...
```

Comment: what happens if you put a  context.HttpContext.Response.Write("hello world 0"); before your first Response.Flush();

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702448/using-a-memorystream-with-filestreamresult-possible
you could possibly use `FileStreamResult` as it takes a `Stream` as a ctor arg

Comment: @jbl
Same behaviour. But after I turned off Fiddler, chrome started to add a file to the list of downloads.

Comment: @wal if I will use FileStreamResult I will have to feed it a memmory stream filled with a data. But in current implementation I can use single download stream and send data to client zipped, just after I got a new chunk.

Comment: it takes a `Stream` not just a `MemoryStream` - i'm not saying it would work but it would compile. you would have to try it. Also, its going to be grossly inefficient to zip things 'on the fly' - sure its convenient the 1st time around but subsequent requests for the same file are going to result in unnecessary zipping

Comment: Seems like a problem with Fiddler - Chrome 25 with no Fiddler shows SaveFile dialog immediately.